# Error using ngFor with Object Array in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I've defined an Array of Objects in my Component class like below :

```
deskCategories : Array<any>;
this.deskCategories = [
        {
            catLabel : 'Tools',
            catIcon : 'suitcase'
        },
        {
            catLabel : 'Accounts',
            catIcon : 'table'
        },
        {
            catLabel : 'File Manager',
            catIcon : 'file'
        },
        {
            catLabel : 'Stock',
            catIcon : 'cubes'
        }
     ];
```

And in my template I'm trying to use it with an ngFor like so :

```
<div class="column" *ngFor="let cat of deskCategories">
    <div class="ui center aligned container">
        <i class="huge {{cat.catIcon}} icon link"></i>
        <p>{{cat.catLabel}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The list gets displayed properly but i get a console error which says :

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./DeskComponent class DeskComponent - inline template:1:24
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: iterator1.next is not a function

Note that it works fine with an array of strings. Is there anything that I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit : Getting this error only in Firefox and Chrome ( Working fine in Edge!)

[image: Error using ngFor Angular 2]

Comment: The code looks fine. Hard to tell without more information.

Comment: could you Re Create your problem on plunker ?

Comment: are you using inline template or templateUrl in .ts

Comment: @mayur I'm using webpack to load the template : template: require('./desk.component.html')

Comment: @PardeepJain I'm unable to reproduce this on plunkr :(

Comment: try using template url onces templateUrl: 'app/modules/DeskComponent .html', or  template: ` <div class="column">........//code......  </div>`,

Comment: @mayur tried that as well, doesn't work. Strangely though, just tried it in Edge and it works fine! Getting this error only in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Then its Clear now  there is no issues in template as well as array.. It seems Some where else issue just for last cut the whole chrome error msg make a png and add the image file lets see might get solution

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using? If you are not sure you are using the latest Angular2 version, try `*ngFor="#cat of deskCategories"` which is deprecated syntax.

Comment: I'm using 2.0.0-rc.1, so can't use the deprecated syntax.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with Ionic2 beta7 but no ngFor in my template. Running on Opera is fine...

[code]
<ion-content>
    <form [ngFormModel]="joinForm" (submit)="join($event)">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item-divider light>By id:</ion-item-divider>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Party id</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="partyId" ngControl="partyId" type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </form>
</ion-content>
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

you have no instance of array at the moment of binding.

try:

```
deskCategories : [];

constructor(){ //this could/should be done in ngOnInit but not super important now

this.deskCategories = [
    {
        catLabel : 'Tools',
        catIcon : 'suitcase'
    },
    {
        catLabel : 'Accounts',
        catIcon : 'table'
    },
    {
        catLabel : 'File Manager',
        catIcon : 'file'
    },
    {
        catLabel : 'Stock',
        catIcon : 'cubes'
    }
 ];
}
```